# Iframe content not loading when an instance of it's route component exists

Tags: angular

so given this snippet:

```
<app-print-result
   *ngIf="!massPrint"
   #printResultComponent
   [widthPx]="printSheetWidthPx"
   [heightPx]="printSheetHeightPx"
></app-print-result>
<iframe
   *ngIf="printing"
   #printableIframe
   class="print-iframe"
   [style.width.px]="printSheetWidthPx"
   [style.height.px]="printSheetHeightPx"
   [src]="sanitizeUrl(iframeSrc)"
></iframe>
```

and knowing that the src of the Iframe will be routed to the PrintResultComponent of the same application that is represented on the snippet as . the iframe will load correctly it's contents if  component shown in the snippet is commented.

Otherwise, the iframe will have its contents set to

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

not initializing the app or giving any error in the devtools console

Can anyone help with this?

Cheers

Comment: your question is not clear. Could you create a stackblitz reproducing the issue?

Comment: it was a problem with the src attribute of the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was a problem with the src attribute of the iframe.